# Ruby not recognising gems from local source, included in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I've had some trouble with gems from a local source before, so set up a simple test project. I haven't had `simple-rss` installed before. This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'simple-rss', :path => '~/code/simple-rss'
```

I then run `bundle install`, it tells me:

```
Using simple-rss 1.2.3 from source at `~/code/simple-rss`
Using bundler 1.12.4
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
```

So then I make test.rb in the same folder as the Gemfile. The test.rb file only has the `require` right now:

```
require 'simple-rss'
```

I run `ruby test.rb`, and get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- simple-rss (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

So that's the first evidence of a problem. I then do:

`sudo gem install simple-rss`

That successfully installs it. I do `ruby test.rb` again, and get no issues. So it's able to run the gem from the *original source* once it's been installed with gem install, but not from the *local source* after running with Bundler.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is it not allowing me to use the gem from the local path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the gems dictated in your Gemfile, I suggest prefixing your commands with `bundle exec`, eg. `bundle exec ruby test.rb`. Otherwise your Ruby will not know about them.